# Unable to change dynamically updated data-id

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to dynamically change the `data-id` of anchor `#a-flop`. The issue is that the `data-id` is only changed once. I am unable to change the dynamically updated value.

HTML

```
 <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-center">
     <li class="dropdown">
         <a id="a-flip" href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
             <i class="fa fa-file-text m-r-10"></i> 
             Invoice 
             <span class="caret"></span>
         </a>
         <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
             <li>
                 <a id="a-flop" data-id="1" href="javascript:void(0)">
                     <i class="fa fa-user m-r-10"></i> 
                     Badge
                 </a>
             </li>
         </ul>
     </li>
 </ul>
```

JQUERY

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $(document).on('click', '#a-flop', function(){
          $this = $(this);
          alert($this.data('id'));
          if ($this.data('id') == 0) {
             $this.attr('data-id', 1);
          } else {                   
             $this.attr('data-id', 0);
          }
      });  
    });
</script>
```

FIDDLE LINK - http://jsfiddle.net/Lv37o8wu/

Comment: Explanation: jQuery reads all the `data-*` attributes and stores them into a internal variable at page load. When you use `.data()`,  you are reading or changing the values from the internal variable and not from the DOM. If you want to **read** or **change** the `data-*` directly into the DOM after loading you need to use `.attr()`. Note that changing the attribute `data-*` with `.attr()` will not change the internal cached variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because you are setting the attribute value and not dom property. you should be using `.data()` to set the value as well:

```
$(document).on('click', '#a-flop', function(){
          $this = $(this);
          alert($this.data('id'));
          if ($this.data('id') == 0) {
             $this.data('id', 1);
          } else {
             $this.data('id', 0);
          }
      });
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/c07s7gez/)**

Comment: Yeah, data properties is stored in cache.